# TypeScript automatic conversion type to integer

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm changing my application from ActionScript to Javascript/TypeScript (because of Flash Player) and I came across a problem, the types of ActionScript automatically converts the number to the given type and I was wondering if this is possible with TypeScript.

Example:

```
function test(x: int, y: int){
    console.log(x, y) //output: 1, 3
}

test(1.5, 3.7)
```

I know I can use the `Math.trunc` function for this, but imagine if I have several int parameters and variables:

```
function test(x: number, y: number, w: number, h: number){
    x = Math.trunc(x)
    y = Math.trunc(y)
    w = Math.trunc(w)
    h = Math.trunc(h)
    
    other: number = 10;
    x = Math.trunc(x / other)
}
```

Note: I'm having to use `Math.trunc` all the time to keep the integer value.

So this is possible with Javascript/TypeScript? If not, there are recommendations from other languages ​​for me to migrate?

Answer (score 3):

There is no `int` type in Typescript or Javascript.

Why not just declare a function variable like this, if you are tired of typing `Math.trunc`:

```
let int = Math.trunc;  // Or choose a name you like
console.log(int(48.9)); // Outputs 48
```

Answer (score 2):

No this can't be done automatically. Typescript doesn't even have an `int` type (except for BigInt, which is a whole other thing)

You could make a utility higher order function that auto-converts number arguments and wrap your functions with it though:

```js
function argsToInt(func) {
  return function(...args) {
    const newArgs = args.map(
      arg => typeof arg === 'number' ? Math.trunc(arg) : arg
    );
    return func(...newArgs);
  }
}

function add(a, b) { 
  return a + b 
}

const addInts = argsToInt(add);

console.log(addInts(2.532432, 3.1273))
console.log(addInts(2.532432, 3.1273)  === 5)
```

That way it will automatically convert any number arguments to ints with out you having to do it everywhere